# (Python3) Can I spawn a single/many child process(es) inside a thread of a multithreaded program?

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing, python-3.5

I have a use case, where a program spawns multiple threads, viz. one for network communication, one for modifying a couple of JSON files, another for querying and writing to a database. These are spawned in multiple threads because all of them are I/O bound tasks.

The code for Network Comm thread, JSON file handler and database handler will be written by me. The database handling can be significantly optimized if use multiple processes as I have multi-core machine.

I want to understand from Python perspective, how will spawning multiple processes inside a thread will work (if it works)?

Comment: Re, "...inside a thread." A thread has no "inside," but there is an interesting question here: Can a Python program _safely_ create a child process after it has created one or more new threads? I don't know the answer to that, but I do know that in the not-too-distant past, there were issues surrounding _any_ program running on some versions of Linux if the program created new processes after creating new threads.

Comment: I once worked on a product where the main program first created a single-threaded "helper" process before it created a whole bunch of threads. Thereafter, when the main program wanted additional new processes, it would ask the single-threaded helper to create them. The whole purpose of that architecture was to work around the limitations of the Linux kernel that everybody was using at that time.

Comment: Thanks Solomon, I like this idea of helper process.

Answer (score 0):

After some more searching, I found a page which closely answers my own question.

As described [in this post](https://web.archive.org/web/20191222152421/https://www.linuxprogrammingblog.com/threads-and-fork-think-twice-before-using-them), it is not a good idea to start a process from a thread. The acquired mutexes in the thread will be duplicated with no way to be freed in child process. Also there are many data race conditions that can happen.

However, I like the Solomon's idea, posted in the comments (to my question) and I will try to go ahead with it Or, may be change my architecture.